# Angular7 httpClient returning type error on post

Tags: angular

I am trying to post an object to a Microsoft Flow http request but it returns a type error of undefined when it errors and I cant seem to fully understand why when I post to the same url using postman successfully.

my service call is

```
 submitComplaint(complaint: Complaint): Observable<any> {
      const body = {
      'Title': complaint.Title,
      'Complaint Type': complaint.ComplaintType.toString(),
      'Complaint Detail': complaint.ComplaintDetail,
      'Contact Email': complaint.ContactEmail,
      'Contact Phone': complaint.ContactPhone,
      'NTU Residence': complaint.NTUResidence.toString()
    };
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
    });
    const params = new HttpParams().set('api-version', '2016-06-01');
    params.append('sp', '/triggers/manual/run');
    params.append('sv', '1.0');
    params.append('sig', '<removed>');

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, body, { headers: headers, params: params })
       .pipe(
         catchError(this.handleError)
       );
  }
```

and my handle error code is

```
   private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
```

Any help?

Edit 1: Snip of console error
[image]

Edit 2: Here is my on submit method to show I am subscribing to the service call.

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.sharepointService.submitComplaint(this.model).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

I have also committed it to my heroku server to see if that helps but returning the same error.

edit 3:
So I having fixed the issue with the url I am being returned with a 404 from Microsoft Flow. Saying the collection doesn't exist. However postman continues to work with the same url?

Comment: do you subscribe to the observable returned?

Comment: can you post the error received too?

Comment: @itdoesntwork yes returns type error undefined

Comment: ok.. the best way to debug this.. use fiddler and postman.. make your request through postman and then through your app.. now use fiddler to see the differences. It's probably cors or a headers issue

Comment: share the screenshot of the error you are getting in `console`

Comment: Its just guess, but do you have CORS on your API. I ask this because I was had a problem in my project when all my controllers in my app go using CORS, but errors returned without right CORS politics. And when I work with API on dev server I can't see right type by CORS politics but on prod everything will work fine.

Comment: @RomanSkydan the api I am posting to is on an azure platform if that sheds any light

Comment: @itdoesntwork fiddler doesn't seem to be capturing the api calls on the submit click.

Comment: @Dashwall does it capture the postman request

Comment: @itdoesntwork yes it does

Comment: do you see your request in the network tab on your browser??

Comment: @itdoesntwork no it doesn't show there either????

Comment: can you please log error?

Comment: sorry I posted the error at part of the stack trace above or were you looking for a different error.

Comment: @itdoesntwork Sorry I have discovered the error is because it is not building out the http params correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186768/discussion-between-dashwall-and-itdoesntwork).